# Android: Google MapView show a progress indicator while map is loading

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there a way to listen if a [`MapView`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView) is still loading? Because I want to show a progress indicator (such as an hourglass) while the `MapView` is downloading the map tiles.

Any solution?

Comment: Hey, did you find any new solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [onDraw](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) documentation for MapView says

> "We draw the map background (loading tiles as appropriate)"

You could try extending MapView and hiding progress indicator as onDraw finishes. But my guess would be that the MapTiles are loaded asynchronously so your progress bar would finish before the MapTiles were all loaded.

Comment: I don't sorry, haven't done any Android dev for a few years now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `OnCameraChangeListener` and `OnMapLoadedCallback` to simulate this behaviour.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener.html) of `GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener`:

> **public abstract void onCameraChange (CameraPosition position)**
>
> Called after the camera position has changed. During an animation,
>   this listener may not be notified of intermediate camera positions. It
>   is always called for the final position in the animation.
>
> This is called on the main thread.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback) of `GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback`:

> **public abstract void onMapLoaded ()**
>
> Called when the map has finished rendering. This will only be called
>   once. You must request another callback if you want to be notified
>   again.

As stated there, `onMapLoaded()` will be only called once, so the strategy could be to request one `GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback` each time the `onCameraChange` is called.

Here is a (very simple) example to illustrate the answer:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnCameraChangeListener, OnMapLoadedCallback {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment=(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();

        googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {
        //TODO: Hide your progress indicator
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(final CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);

        //TODO: Show your progress indicator
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely what I was looking for. Seems like it takes too much time for `onMapLoaded()` to be called, but it is because the map loads all the places, etc. Definitely the right API. Thank you! Should be the accepted answer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API to doing this in current `MapView` implementation.