# Cluster manager MarkerCollection updated completed

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using google map clustering utility, when map is clustered and change zoom programmatically, some markers render automatically as expected, I need to catch event when all markers are done. Is there any way?

```
public void OnCameraChange (CameraPosition position)
        {
            _clusterManager.OnCameraChange (position);

            if (_markerClicked && _activeMerchant != null) {
                Marker marker = _clusterManager.MarkerCollection.Markers.FirstOrDefault (x => x.Snippet == _activeMerchant.MerchantId);
                if (marker != null) {
                    OnMarkerClick (marker);
                }
            }
        }
```

here some markers are not rendered yet.

Comment: You can use `GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback` that fires when the map has finished rendering. Is a bit tricky cause the callback is called once and you need to request another callback if you want to be notified again. Take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192782/android-google-mapview-show-a-progress-indicator-while-map-is-loading/33234331#33234331